# Unable to start (SysV init) script with systemd service in RHEL 8.2

Tags: linux, systemd, rhel, sysvinit

I'm facing an issue where `ExecStart` of a `SysV init` script is failing in RHEL 8.2. I don't have this issue in RHEL 7.9 with the exact same init script and service unit setup. Went through quite a bit of resources online, but still not able to find out what the root cause is for this problem. Whether it's due to `systemd` version or an incompatibility between `SysV init` and `systemd` in RHEL 8.2. Understand that ideally I should convert it to a service unit but due to certain requirements I cannot do this.

RHEL 8.2 `systemd` version: `v239`

RHEL 7.9 `systemd` version: `v219`

`/etc/systemd/system/mq.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=MQ service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/rc.mq start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/rc.mq stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/etc/init.d/rc.mq` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 35 95 5

function fstart
{
  su - mqm -c "strmqm QMNAME" > /dev/null 2>&1
}

function fstop
{
  su - mqm -c "endmqm -i QMNAME"
  sleep 30
}

case $1 in
  start)
        fstart
        break;;
  stop)
        fstop
        break;;
  restart)
        fstop
        fstart
        break;;
  *)
    fstart
    break;;
esac
exit
```

`$ systemctl status mq.service`:

```
● mq.service - MQ service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mq.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2021-07-06 16:03:43 +08; 27s ago
  Process: 66183 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/rc.mq stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 66084 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/rc.mq start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 06 16:03:10 hostname.company.com su[66085]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user mqm by (uid=0)
Jul 06 16:03:10 hostname.company.com su[66085]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user mqm by (uid=0)
Jul 06 16:03:11 hostname.company.com su[66085]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user mqm
Jul 06 16:03:11 hostname.company.com su[66085]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user mqm
Jul 06 16:03:11 hostname.company.com su[66188]: (to mqm) root on none
Jul 06 16:03:11 hostname.company.com su[66188]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user mqm by (uid=0)
Jul 06 16:03:11 hostname.company.com su[66188]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user mqm by (uid=0)
Jul 06 16:03:11 hostname.company.com rc.mq[66183]: IBM MQ queue manager 'QMNAME' ending.
Jul 06 16:03:13 hostname.company.com rc.mq[66183]: IBM MQ queue manager 'QMNAME' ended.
Jul 06 16:03:43 hostname.company.com systemd[1]: Started MQ service.
```

`$ journalctl -xe`:

```
Jul 06 15:10:17 hostname.company.com systemd[1]: Starting MQ service...
-- Subject: Unit mq.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
--
-- Unit mq.service has begun starting up.
Jul 06 15:10:17 hostname.company.com systemd[1]: Started system activity accounting tool.
-- Subject: Unit sysstat-collect.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
--
-- Unit sysstat-collect.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Jul 06 15:10:17 hostname.company.com su[62138]: (to mqm) root on none
Jul 06 15:10:17 hostname.company.com su[62138]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user mqm by (uid=0)
Jul 06 15:10:17 hostname.company.com systemd[1]: Started Session c513 of user mqm.
-- Subject: Unit session-c513.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
--
-- Unit session-c513.scope has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Jul 06 15:10:17 hostname.company.com su[62138]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user mqm by (uid=0)
Jul 06 15:10:17 hostname.company.com su[62138]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user mqm
Jul 06 15:10:17 hostname.company.com su[62138]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user mqm
Jul 06 15:10:17 hostname.company.com su[62245]: (to mqm) root on none
Jul 06 15:10:17 hostname.company.com su[62245]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user mqm by (uid=0)
Jul 06 15:10:17 hostname.company.com systemd[1]: Started Session c514 of user mqm.
-- Subject: Unit session-c514.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
--
-- Unit session-c514.scope has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Jul 06 15:10:17 hostname.company.com su[62245]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user mqm by (uid=0)
Jul 06 15:10:17 hostname.company.com rc.mq[62238]: IBM MQ queue manager 'QMNAME' ending.
Jul 06 15:10:19 hostname.company.com rc.mq[62238]: IBM MQ queue manager 'QMNAME' ended.
Jul 06 15:10:19 hostname.company.com su[62245]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user mqm
Jul 06 15:10:19 hostname.company.com su[62245]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user mqm
Jul 06 15:10:49 hostname.company.com systemd[1]: Started MQ service.
-- Subject: Unit mq.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
--
-- Unit mq.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
```

Tried changing `ExecStart` to `ExecStart=/sbin/service rc.mq start` or running this `export _SYSTEMCTL_SKIP_REDIRECT=1`, it is still the same.

May I know what might be the cause of this? Again, this setup works in RHEL 7.9.

**Edit****

Found out that the following parameter in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` file is preventing the service from starting up, any idea why?

```
-session    optional      pam_systemd.so
```

Comment: It might be fixed by a once-only setting from root for user mqm: ` loginctl enable-linger mqm`, as I think the default changed at some stage.

Comment: did this but the mqm user session still closes as found in the journal

Comment: hi @meuh, with reference to my edit, seems that ```-session    optional      pam_systemd.so``` in ```/etc/pam.d/system-auth``` is causing this. Do you know why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about the interaction of pam and systemd. You might try a different approach: remove the `su mqm` from the `rc.mq` file, and set `User=mqm` in the `[Service]` part of the `mq.service` file.